# create consolidated build report from multiple jenkins instances

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am having multiple jenkins instances like Jenkins A, Jenkins B and Jenkins C.
Now I am trying to make a report which will have the details about all of the three jenkins at one place.

report about : "Total Build", "Success", "Failed". 
( from jenkins A,Jenkins B, Jenkins C)

Is there any shell script which runs on every Jenkins Instances and combine the Script Output at one place?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure anonymous has read access to all your jobs in jenkins. Use powershell to invoke the job's url in the following format
http://jenkinsA:8080/view/viewname/job/jobname/1/console
http://jenkinsA:8080/view/viewname/job/jobname/2/console
http://jenkinsB:8080/view/viewname/job/jobname/1/console
http://jenkinsC:8080/view/viewname/job/jobname/2/console

Keep a count for the number of possible builds for each job. Each time your count is incremented, create an http request in powershell to invoke the url. If the request returns 404, you know the build does not exist and if it is http 200, the build exists. extract the line 'Finished:' which will give you either success or failure.

Based on the results, increment your success or failure count.

Hope it helps!